# Order By Count in results

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble working out how to order results by the count of results.What I would like to do is have the results as ordered by the amount of occurences of product:

Data:

```
userID | product
     1 | 3
     1 | 4
     1 | 5
     2 | 3
     2 | 5
```

Expected results:

```
product
3
5
4
```

The results also need to exlude the current product so I have solved this by using a subquery:

```
SELECT Product,userID FROM ProductTable WHERE userID IN(SELECT userID FROM productViewed WHERE Product="4817") AND Product<>"4817"
```

I have tried Count(product) with Group By and Order by but this doesn't seem to work.

Is this the correct way to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 1):

Check this SQL Fiddle for your answer

[**Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd7672/13)

Query:

```
select product from ProductTable
group by product order by count(userId) desc;
```

In this query, add your sub-query to exclude the products as per requirement.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT 
product FROM 
(SELECT 
product,COUNT(userid) AS cnt 
FROM producttable 
GROUP BY product) as a 
WHERE product<>'excluding product' 
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```